# XSLT Syntax error

Tags: xslt

can any one validate the below xslt syntax

```
<xsl:if test="(string(Address/Country)=='US') || (string(Address/Country)=='CA')">
      <val name="PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_StateProvinceCd">
       <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Address/State)" />
      </val>  
     </xsl:if>
```

when i am trying the above i got below error 
"ERROR:  'Syntax error in '(string(Address/Country)=='US') or (string(Address/Country)=='CA')'.'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
"

Thanks in advance
Ramana

Answer (score 0):

The `==` is not valid XPath. The equals operator is a single character, `=`.

Comment: I modified == to =, but still i got "ERROR: 'Syntax error in '(string(Address/Country)=='US') or (string(Address/Country)=='CA')'.' FATAL ERROR: 'Could not compile stylesheet' "

Comment: can you plz verify the syntax once .

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <xsl:if test="(string(Address/Country)=='US') || (string(Address/Country)=='CA')">
> ```

**There are *two* syntax errors here**:

1. There is no `==` operator in XPath. You probably want to use the `=` operator.
2. There is no `||` operator in XPath. You probably want to use the `or` operator.

**The corrected code will look like**:

```
<xsl:if test="(string(Address/Country) = 'US') or (string(Address/Country) ='CA')">
```

**The brackets aren't necessary, because `or` has lower priority than `=`** :

```
<xsl:if test="string(Address/Country) = 'US' or string(Address/Country) ='CA'">
```